# while loop condition - search for string pattern in bash

Tags: bash

I am altering a bash script and I need to write a loop and test if file of a specific pattern exists in source directory.

Script works if I designate a specific file but not with a wild card (`file_patt*`, for example).  Any ideas?

```
while [[ ! -e $SRC_DIR/file_patt* ]] ; do 
    echo "in loop"
done
```

Comment: Is this what you are trying to do?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6363441/check-if-a-file-exists-with-wildcard-in-shell-script  One of the answers might be helpful

Comment: You will never get file expansion inside `[[ ... ]]`: you must use single brackets. The other comments in @Val's link explain what's required, and Marian's solution is the neatest.

Comment: I think something like [`inotifywait`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/inotifywait) is a better solution

Comment: @glennjackman cool!

Comment: Also see [How can I check whether a directory is empty or not? How do I check for any *.mpg files, or count how many there are? (Greg's Wiki)](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/004)

Answer (score 0):

I think I could solve your problem on a fairly simple way.

I do not want to use not built-in functions:

```
unset i
rm *.txtx
# Now it is sure no matching file is in this dir
while a=(*.txtx) [ ! -e "$a" ]; do
   echo loop $i; 
   [ $((++i)) -eq 5 ] && >a.txtx # Creates a matching file if i == 5
done
ls *.txtx
```

Output is:

```
loop
loop 1
loop 2
loop 3
loop 4
loop 5
a.txtx
```

It is not enough to check the size of the array, as if there is no file matching to the pattern then the size of the array will be 1 containing the pattern `*.txtx`. But there can be a file named `*.txtx`, so `-e` has to be used to check if the result is just the pattern itself or a real file.

If more matching files are created in the loop it is still works as `$a` is the same as `${a[0]}`.

I hope this helps!